# c# faster n-ary cartesian product for

Tags: c#

I have searched around for a way to find the product of multiple lists; I have used the popular answer which uses Aggregate+SelectMany. The trouble is that my example runs very slow: I have 4 lists, with 3K entries each and I need to enumerate each possible combinations.

Does anyone know a faster way in C#?

I made a fiddle [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/kG7E9r), which currently runs out of memory.

Following is the code of fiddle link

```
public static void Main()
{
    var sources = new[]
    {
        Enumerable.Range(1, 3000),  
        Enumerable.Range(1, 3000),
        Enumerable.Range(1, 3000),
        Enumerable.Range(1, 3000),
    };
    var sw = new System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch();
    sw.Start();
    Console.Write("linq way...");

    foreach(var l in NCartesian(sources))
    {
        // just enumerate   
    }

    Console.WriteLine("{0}ms", sw.ElapsedMilliseconds);
}

public static IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>> NCartesian<T>(
    IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>> sequences)
{
    if (sequences == null)
    {
        return null;
    }

    IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>> emptyProduct = new[] { Enumerable.Empty<T>() 
};

    return sequences.Aggregate(
        emptyProduct,
        (accumulator, sequence) => accumulator.SelectMany(
            accseq => sequence,
            (accseq, item) => accseq.Concat(new[] { item })));
}
```

Comment: Without code it's not possible for us to help you. Please edit your question to include your current code. See [ask] for more information: _"If it is possible to create a live example of the problem that you can link to [...] then do so - but also copy the code into the question itself. Not everyone can access external sites, and the links may break over time."_

Comment: It would be awesome if you could provide a [mcve].

Comment: As @mjwills said, you should put your code on post, not just fiddle.

Comment: I thought a fiddle would be better than a code snippet; it is a working example of how slow it is. Not sure what is the issue here.

Answer (score 0):

I made one which has less memory usage than the above, still slow though:

```
public static IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>> NCartesian<T>(
        IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>> sequences)
    {
        if (sequences == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(sequences));
        }

        var enumerators = new List<IEnumerator<T>>();
        foreach (IEnumerator<T> enumerator in sequences
            .Select(s => s.GetEnumerator()))
        {
            enumerator.MoveNext(); // move to the first position
            enumerators.Add(enumerator);
        }

        bool done = false;
        while (!done)
        {
            IList<T> result = enumerators.Select(e => e.Current).ToList();

            yield return result;

            for (int idx = enumerators.Count - 1; idx >= 0; idx--)
            {
                bool hasNext = enumerators[idx].MoveNext();
                if (hasNext)
                {
                    break;
                }

                if (idx == 0)
                {
                    // the first enumerator is done
                    done = true;
                    break;
                }

                enumerators[idx].Reset();
                enumerators[idx].MoveNext();
            }
        }
    }
```